# Service semantic checking

Tags: java, microservices, integration-testing, pact

Is there a way I could semantically check service and know that its behaviour is right? Like PACT is for checking syntactically. Is there a way to test whether the response I am getting is the one I expected?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by behaviour, you're meaning validating invariants across multiple requests, e.g. "If I (successfully) `PUT /foo/bar/baz` with body `{ "qux": "quux" }`, then `GET /foo/bar/baz`, the response is `{ "qux": "quux" }`.

I don't know if there are any tools that would directly help with this, but the general approach that's used in Akka's Behavior TestKit for testing actors (which are isomorphic to potentially stateful microservices) would be applicable.  The basic idea is that the state of the service and how it responds to requests are effectively one and the same (two states are different exactly to the extent there are requests that yield different responses from those states).

So the basic approach would be to, for each individual test case, to spin up an instance of the service (likely with dependencies stubbed out) and make requests to it, collecting the responses.  Depending on implementation choices in the microservice, this may be difficult to impossible, especially around automating the set-up and tear-down.

Comment: What you're describing is exactly what Pact does. I don't know how a tool can check functional behaviour as OP is asking however, because if it were expressible by syntax alone it wouldnt require asking - I would be keen to know!